# 20.04 Gnome X2Go Artifacting

Tags: gnome, x2go, x2goclient

I'm wondering how to reduce the number of artifacts/glitches in X2go. For example, I often see icons on the desktop appear through the current window (e.g. fullscreen or full windowed Firefox). Are there particular connection settings or additional packages that might improve X2Go "quality" in this regard?

Server: Ubunutu 20.04
Packages:

```
libx2go-config-perl/focal,focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 all [installed,automatic]
libx2go-log-perl/focal,focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 all [installed,automatic]
libx2go-server-db-perl/focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libx2go-server-perl/focal,focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 all [installed,automatic]
libx2go-utils-perl/focal,focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 all [installed,automatic]
x2goserver-common/focal,focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 all [installed,automatic]
x2goserver-extensions/focal,focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 all [installed,automatic]
x2goserver-fmbindings/focal,focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 all [installed,automatic]
x2goserver-printing/focal,focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 all [installed,automatic]
x2goserver-x2goagent/focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
x2goserver-xsession/focal,focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 all [installed]
x2goserver/focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 amd64 [installed]
```

Client: Linux Mint, Android, Ubuntu
Packages:

```
libx2go-config-perl/focal,focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 all [installed,automatic]
libx2go-log-perl/focal,focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 all [installed,automatic]
libx2go-server-db-perl/focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libx2go-server-perl/focal,focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 all [installed,automatic]
libx2go-utils-perl/focal,focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 all [installed,automatic]
x2goclient/focal,now 4.1.2.2-1 amd64 [installed]
x2goserver-common/focal,focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 all [installed,automatic]
x2goserver-x2goagent/focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
x2goserver-xsession/focal,focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 all [installed]
x2goserver/focal,now 4.1.0.3-5 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: I assume you are using X-server, not wayland?

Comment: Likely, given that Ubuntu is x11 by default from what I remember? Same for my other distributions acting as clients unless LM Cinnamon has recently changed.